# Passing a non-serializable object to another activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have an object of type `ArrayList<StorageReference>` which I need to pass to the next activity but since the `StorageReference` class is not serializable ( I assume ) when I try to pass it using the `Bundle` class I get a
`AndroidRuntime error: Parcel: unable to marshal value` error.

So what can I do to pass it though? Is there any workaround?

Comment: simply create a singeltom class add your method there  and access it everywhere..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first convert each StorageReference into a string using [getPath()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference#getPath()) before adding them to the Bundle.  Then, in the receiving activity, convert those strings back into StorageReference objects using [FirebaseStorage.getReference(String)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/FirebaseStorage#getReference(java.lang.String)).